# Ranges on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns, cola and colb, which represent a range of numbers.

Example problem:

```
cola - colb
1    - 10
11   - 22
33   - 66
67   - 67
```

- if the input is 7-8, I would like a query that would extract the range 1-10.
- if the input is 67 - 80, I would like a query that would extract 67 - 67

Example query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM example 
 WHERE vala >= cola 
   AND valb <= colb
```

The first criterion works great with the above query however it falls down when cola = colb ie.. 67 - 67.

---

The above is a simple example of my issue.. The problem is actually a range of Ips. 
Cola - Colb2 = Ip range. I have included in case something is missing in the above example.

```
   SELECT *
     FROM `static_allocation`

    WHERE INET_ATON('$network_addr')   >= INET_ATON(network_addr)
      AND INET_ATON('$broadcast_addr') <= INET_ATON(broadcast_addr)

    LIMIT 1
```

---

Edit:

OK, it appears i am slightly wrong ..

Table data

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.15 
10.0.0.16 - 10.0.0.16
```

however when i try and select `10.0.0.16 - 10.0.0.20`, it doesn't find the record..

Comment: Isn't it because valb is 80 and is not less or equal to 67?

Comment: I think the question is about IP ranges.  The network address of `192.1.1.5` is `192.1.1.0`, and its broadcast address is `192.1.1.255` @TigOldBitties: right missed the 80 there

Comment: hmm, ok, i've tracked the problem a little.. It appears i was wrong.. 1 - 16 is fine, then 17 - 17... then i try 17 - 20.. this is where the problem happens..

Comment: I've added an edit, after investigating a little more.

Comment: what happens if you enter the number directly, instead of using INET_ATON? This should help with debugging?

Comment: exactly the same issue :(.. I think its more  my logic on the comparison..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the first range that contains at least a part of the block, try a condition like:

```
vala <= colb and cola <= valb
```

This says the search range `[vala,valb]` must partially overlap with the target range `[cola,colb]`.

In SQL:

```
select  *
from    example
where   vala <= colb and cola <= valb
order by
        cola -- Lowest network range
limit   1
```